# This while loop is not working and more time, even I give the condition

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I used while loop to take data from the database and I give the condition, but the loop is repeated polytime even I am stopping from the browser and if I put break just it displays one record. if I remove the break it again more and more records.

```
<?php
$db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","done");
$query="SELECT * FROM dones where id>3";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$query); 
$x=0;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $x++;
  echo '<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">';
  echo '<div class="card" style="margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px;">';
   echo '<div class="card-header" id="headingOne">';
     echo '<h5 class="mb-0">';
      echo  '<button class="btn btn-link" style="text-decoration:none; font- 
  family:Times New Roman, Times, serif; font-size:18px; " type="button" 
  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" 
  aria-controls="collapseOne">';
      echo   $row['title'];

       echo '</button>';
      echo '</h5>';
    echo '</div>';

   echo '<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria- 
   labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">';
   echo  '<div class="card-body">';



   echo '<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
   style="height:430px;">';
   echo '<h5 style="text-align:left; margin-left:20px; margin-top:20px;"> 
   <small>Title</small></h5>';
   echo '<input style="width:290px; margin-left:158px; height:30px; margin- 
   top:-30px;" name="title" type="text" class="form-control" 
   placeholder="Title">';
   echo ' <br>';
   echo ' <div class="custom-file" style="height:10px; width:290px; margin- 
   right:1050px; top-padding:20px; float:right;">';
   echo ' <input type="file" name="uploadfile" class="custom-file-input" 
   id="validatedCustomFile">';
   echo ' <label class="custom-file-label" for="validatedCustomFile">Choose 
   file...</label>';
   echo ' </div>';
   echo ' <h5 style="text-align:left; margin-left:20px;"><small>File</small> 
   </h5>';
   echo ' <br>';
   echo ' <h5 style="text-align:left; margin-left:20px;"><small>Banner 
   Image</small></h5>';
   echo ' <div style="height:130px; width:290px; border-width:1px; border- 
   style:solid; float:right; margin-right:1050px; margin-top:-15px;">';

     $db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","done");
     $sql="SELECT image FROM dones where status=1";
     $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
     $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
     echo '<img src= "images/'.$data['image'].'" style="height:130px; 
    width:290px;">';

     echo '</div>';
     echo '<br>';
     echo '<br>';
     echo '<br>';
     echo '<br>';
     echo '<br>';
     echo '<br>';  
     echo '<h5 style="text-align:left; margin-left:20px;"> 
    <small>Status</small></h5>';
     echo '<select name="status" id="" style="width:290px; float:right; 
     margin-right:1050px; margin-top:-25px;">';
     echo '<option value="1" name="enable">Enable</option>';
     echo '<option value="0" name="disable">Disable</option>';
     echo '</select>';
     echo '<br>';
     echo '<br>';
     echo '<button type="submit" name="tbsubmit"  style="margin-left:250px;" 
     class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>';   
     echo '</div>';

     echo '</form>';
     echo '</div>';



    echo  '</div>';
   echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
   echo '</div>';

  }   

  ?>
```

just I want to repeat this loop, up to how many recordes I have in the database not more or less.

Comment: Finally what you want, you want to display only one record or multiple records? there is no clarity in your question

Comment: Why have you done 2 db connections ??

Comment: I want to display multiple record from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are re-using the first result set variable `$result` ...

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

inside the while loop...

```
 $db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","done");
 $sql="SELECT image FROM dones where status=1";
 $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
 $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

You can replace this with (also dropping the connection as you don't need to reconnect each time)...

```
 $sql="SELECT image FROM dones where status=1";
 $result1=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
 $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
```